# Integrating a function of two variables with respect to one on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to have MATLAB integrate a function of two variables, like `fun=@(x,y)x+y;`
against one variable. I can define, say `fun2=@(y)quad(@(x)fun(x,y),1,2);` and it'll give me `fun2(1)`, say, no problem. But it gives me errors when I try to evaluate `fun2` of a, say, matrix. When I try to integrate `fun2` using `quad()`, which is what I need to do, it gives me the same error.

And I can't just use `quad2d()` because (a) I need something like `fun2` in several different places and (b) the integrals I need to calculate are 4D.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: could you give some exemplary values of x (and y) where you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the fun2 for every element of an array. You can do this by using the arrayfun and define fun2.

You can see the info on arrayfun at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html.

Comment: Well not just that; I was giving that as an example of what it can't do. What I need is to be able to integrate fun2 against y, which gives the same error. I can't use quad2d, because (a) I need to use something like fun2 in several places and (b) the integrals I need to calculate are 4D.

Comment: The arrayfun accepts arrays, no matter their dimensions. So, I guess that maybe you have to clarify better what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `quad`, use `integral` with the 'ArrayValued' property set to true.

```
fun2 = @(y)integral(@(x)fun(x,y),1,2,'ArrayValued',true);
```

For your four-dimensional problem, you can use `integral(@(x)integral3(…))` or `arrayfun`. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141102/quadruple-integral-using-nested-integral2-in-matlab/25143106#25143106) how to do this exactly.

You should use `integral` instead of `quad` anyway, because the [Matlab quad documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/quad.html) says:

```
quad will be removed in a future release. Use integral instead.
```

In the [documentation of integral](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), you also find options that specify the accuracy of the result ('AbsTol' and 'RelTol').

Comment: Stupid question, but will that still give the same degree of accuracy as `quad`?